# How to repair integrated window screens from a 1930s house?

Tags: windows, hardware, old-house, screens

I'm purchasing a house built in 1937. All the windows and fixtures are original.

A fair number of the windows have an integrated screen that pulls down from the top of the window. The tracks are attached to the window, and I believe there is a roller integrated in the frame. I'm not sure what they are called, but I've attached photos below. Not knowing what they are called makes finding information about them difficult.

Most of the screens are like the one in the picture, and pretty much toast, but the few that still have intact screens work well (or would with some grease/oil). What is this mechanism called? Can it be repaired? Can I add lubricant without breaking the frame?

[image: attachment to frame]

[image: track in frame]

Comment: Neat system. There should be/probably is a way to access the working parts, but it may involve breaking a lot of paint, by the look of things. Hunt for screws under the paint for a start. Might also be worth a look from the outside, but probably not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had windows with screens similar to yours in my first 1950's house. They were built by" Pella" window and doors. I would contact them 1st. to see if they are their window and ask if they have a solution. If they are not their windows they may be able to direct you to the actual manufacturer.

Comment: By the way, at that time the screens were call roll screens according to Pella.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. It looks like the outside does not have access either.